# Is there a way to add a line break between the plot and X axis (vega-lite)

Tags: vega-lite

I am not sure if it makes sense but will it be possible to add a line break between the start of the plot and the X-axis.

For e.g.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": {"step": 10},
  "height": 120,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal", "scale": {"round": false}},
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Hopeful output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding a `scale.domain` argument:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": {"step": 10},
  "height": 120,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal", "scale": {"round": false}},
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [-0.5, 6]}}
  }
}
```

[image]

Another way to do this is to use the `y` and `y2` encodings to set a bottom value for the area chart:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": {"step": 10},
  "height": 120,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "area",
  "transform": [{"calculate": "0.1", "as": "bottom"}],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal", "scale": {"round": false}},
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y2": {"field": "bottom"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @jakevdp. This is very helpful.
But, the above solution doesn't seem to work if the 'X' axis is continuous as well.

Didn't work for this example: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/layer_histogram_global_mean.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean ween you say it doesn't seem to work? I tried applying both the above methods to that example, and they both worked as expected (keep in mind you have to adjust the values, because the y scale is larger by a couple orders of magnitude)

Comment: My bad. It works. Earlier, was not setting the scale correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do something similar, adding it as another answer to make it convenient for others.

`offset` property of [axis](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html) shifts the axis line by fixed pixels, independent of the data. Using `offset` adds a gap between the `x` and `y` axis lines though.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": {"step": 10},
  "height": 120,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Name", "type": "nominal", "scale": {"round": false}, "axis": {"offset": 5}},
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```